# Erase SSD with a hammer

Tags: ssd, physical-damage

I have a damaged solid state drive with **SENSITIVE DATA**. I can't use software erasing methods as the SSD couldn't be read by the computer anymore.

In comparison, a damaged hard drive, may be drilled to further reduce the chances of sensitive data being read once acquired by another person.

**Question 1:** Is it possible to erase its contents by just using a hammer to smash the flash chips inside it?

> Is this a rhetorical question? If you physically destroy the drive including the chips, it doesn't make any difference whether there is still data stored on the pieces since there is no way to access it. — fixer1234

A clarification on the question due to @fixer1234's comment:

**Question 2:**
If there would be someone with a technical expertise, who can acquire a thrown drive and re-power the drive in some other way. For instance, if the ports were the only part damaged in the drive, and if it were replaced and re-soldered by the one who acquired the drive, would it be safer, to just smash the chips for it to be unreadable at all?

Or is the chips too durable, that the data can still be present despite by applying physical force to it, such as a hammer.

> **Note:** I am using a hammer in this scenario, as it is the one of the most possible item to exist in a common household.

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?  If you physically destroy the drive including the chips, it doesn't make any difference whether there is still data stored on the pieces since there is no way to access it.

Comment: Maybe someone can access the drive in some kind of way. That's why I want to be safe, although it doesn't have that much of sensitive data, it's still data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Erase", no, but it *would* likely make it more difficult to recover.

Many modern drives *do* come with onboard encryption or at least scramble the contents of their drive - depending on the nature of the damage and the drive, it might already be mostly irrecoverable

*Smashing up* a SSD is probably going to be terrible for you, with all that fibreglass and epoxy dust. Even then, those components are pretty damage resistant. You'd be better off desoldering the chips (as haphazardly as you desire) and disposing of the controller, and memory chips seperately at a local e-waste disposal centre(s).

If you *must* use a hammer, it might make sense to stick nails through the chips (and wantonly damage/short components), which would presumably do very unpleasant things to the internals. ... If you had a friend with a [hydraulic press](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rux_0I-UqNw) or a a drill press, it might be more efficient at totalling the drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can't erase the flash devices that way, but you can destroy them so that no one will ever be able to read them any more (1).

If you are pedantic about it, throw away the smashed up parts in different locations.

(1) Except if they would throw lots of money at it to assemble the flash devices and use an electron microscope to read the individual memory cells.

Why would you do it though. Is there sensitive data on the SSD?

Comment: It doesn't have that much of sensitive data in it, but then again it's still data so I might as well damage it to a point of destruction.

Answer (score -2):

Of course it would: if you smash up the chips that store the data, then it would be irrecoverable. You can't actually erase data anyway, just overwrite the contents with off switches, making it nothing to whatever computer wants to read it.

Comment: Downvoters, can you explain? This answer is not terrific, but also not incorrect.